# Should the gitolite user also be the gitolite-admin user?

Tags: git, gitolite

I have a project with a small number of students and wanted to use a `gitolite` setup to work jointly on it. So I asked my sys-admin and he installed `gitolite3` from the repositories on an `ubuntu 16.04` server.

At some point he asked me for my public ssh-key since he was asked in the installation process to provide the admin's ssh-key. After that was done, I accessed the server (let's call it `server`) with my standard user account (named `user`) that is also the admin for gitolite:

```
ssh user@server
```

Following the gitolite documentation, I did the following (as `user`)

```
git clone gitolite3@server:gitolite-admin
cd gitolite-admin
```

Then I created some repo by modifying the file `conf/gitolite.conf`. After adding the public key of one of the students, I realized that I should have probably done the above `git clone` as user `gitolite3` which was automatically created during the installation process.

As I have done it now, `user` is both the admin and a normal user contributing to the project, which is probably not ideal.

My question therefore: Do I have to do a `su - gitolite3` *before* configuring gitolite (by cloning the gitolide-admin repository)? If so, I should probably also generate the ssh-key as `gitolite3` user, I guess...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to do a `su - gitolite3` before configuring gitolite

From the [fool-proof installation process](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/fool_proof_setup/), you need to create a dedicated account, that you then use for the URL of the admin repo, after an `su`.

> This will be the hosting user. ("hosting user" means when you're done installing, your users will use URLs like `git@server:reponame` or `ssh://git@server/reponame`).

The first `git clone` is done as `gitlolite3` (or `git` in my example), in order to call `gitolite/install` and then to setup the `ron.pub` public key as an admin: `$HOME/bin/gitolite setup -pk /tmp/ron.pub`

Then `ron` is able to clone that admin repo. The rest is done from the regular account.

---

> generate the ssh-key as gitolite3 user

No. You generate your keys as your original account.

And you use your public key (of your regular account) in the setup process:

```
cd $HOME
$HOME/bin/gitolite setup -pk /tmp/ron.pub
```

Comment: Just to be sure: all the administration tasks (adding new users and repositories), starting with the initial `git clone git@server:gitolite-admin`  is supposed to be done with my regular account, `Ron` in the example and *not* as `gitlolite3` user (or `git` as it is called in your example)?

Comment: @Alf The first git clone is done as gitlolite3, in order to call `gitolite/install` and then to setup the ron.pub public key as an admin: `$HOME/bin/gitolite setup -pk /tmp/ron.pub`. *Then* you can clone that same repo as you. And start adding users.

Comment: thanks :)   In this case, however, the installation was done by the sys-admin from the repos and the only interaction was my public key he needed to set me up as the gitolite admin. (Therefore, no explicit `gitolite/install` call)